# mediaplayer play internet mp3 ：java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
public void playSound(String uri,int flag)
    {
        Uri uri1=Uri.parse(uri);
        ContestVoteFragment fragment = (ContestVoteFragment) fragments.get(0);
        if (fragment.playSound(flag))
        {
            if (mediaPlayer==null)
            {
                mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(uri);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }else {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(uri);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }else {
            if (mediaPlayer!=null)
            {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when i play a internet mp3 ,the error message is Couldn't open http://p9snltngh.bkt.clouddn.com/Fs3M3Cq_Mkex9AsunJt57N22JQp2: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider
i can’t understand because “http://p9snltngh.bkt.clouddn.com/FhEbUwGYcmQbXIVMVzd0GyPypDVC”this uri can play

Comment: Both the links did not open in Chrome.

Comment: I can open in Chrome….

Comment: It opened in Mozilla though.

Comment: Is `URI` a string?

Comment: Yes, is a string

Comment: Please try the solution.

Answer (score 0):

both links are working

```
public void playSound(String uri){
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(uri);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** You need to parse your String URI into the URI class. So,

Instead of:

```
 try {
     mediaPlayer.setDataSource(uri);
     mediaPlayer.prepare();
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Try like this:

```
 try {
     mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(uri));
     mediaPlayer.prepare();
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```